# CTE Recursive by Minutes

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

I'm trying to make a CTE Recursive code that tells me both the date and time but changes by the minute.

```
DECLARE @MinDate date = '02/10/18'
       ,@EndDate date = DATEADD(MINUTE, n, '00:00:00')

WITH MinuteData As
(
    SELECT @MinDate AS TimeStamp
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(MINUTE, 1, TimeStamp)
    From MinuteData
    Where TimeStamp < @EndDate
)
```

Comment: Expected result set or output?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: this really sounds like should be done without a recursive cte

Comment: Did u tried this `option (maxrecursion 0)`

Comment: No question, incomplete SQL *(nothing that uses the CTE)*, invalid SQL *(you can't add `n` minutes)*, seemingly nonsense literal values *(adding minutes to the TIME `'00:00:00'`?)*, strange data-type choices *(adding minutes, but then storing in DATE variables?)*.  Please read up on how to ask a question?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? That query has some product specific parts.

Comment: You are new here (welcome!), people are sometimes rather harsh. Please tag with the actual RDBMS (product and version) and please read [How to ask a good SQL question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056)  and [How to create a MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Asking a **good question** is the best guarantee for fast and reliable answers...

Answer (score 1):

You did not state your RDBMS. This code is for SQL-Server which you might have to adapt for another product (for the next time: Always state your RDBMS with the actual version as question tag!)

If I get this correctly, you just want to get a list of `DATETIME` values, each increased by one minute between a given start and a given end.

Try something like this

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME={d'2018-10-02'};
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME={ts'2018-10-02 12:30:00'};

WITH Tally AS
( SELECT TOP(60*24) ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))-1 AS Nmbr 
  FROM master..spt_values)
SELECT DATEADD(MINUTE,Nmbr,@StartDate) AS YourChangingDateTime
FROM Tally
WHERE DATEADD(MINUTE,Nmbr,@StartDate)<=@EndDate;
```

The cte "Tally" will create a numbers table on the fly. You might also use a physical numbers table - very handsome for many issues!

`TOP (60*24)` is the count of minutes of 1 day, you can change this, if you need more.

`master..spt_values` is just a prefilled table with quite a lot of values. It's the easiest way to *simulate* a list with many rows.

Answer (score 0):

How about using `datetime`s?

```
DECLARE @MinDateTime datetime = '2018-02-10',
        @EndDateTime datetime = DATEADD(MINUTE, n, @MinDateTime);

WITH MinuteData As (
      SELECT @MinDateTime AS TimeStamp
      UNION ALL
      SELECT DATEADD(MINUTE, 1, TimeStamp)
      From MinuteData
      Where TimeStamp < @EndDateTime
    )
```